# Show a subset of my models data in Django Admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

my database model is like

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    email_sent = models.BooleanField(null=True, default=False)
    rest_owner = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='rest_owner')
    is_approved = models.BooleanField(null=False, default=False)
```

I want to create a separate table where I can show data of just fields where **is_approved=0** . its simple in django Site. But I am unable to find a way to do this in djangoAdmin side. Or I have to make a custom admin for this ?

Comment: Have you already configured Django's admin for Restaurant? Could you show your admin.py?

Comment: @NicoGriffioen No I have't .there is only other models register not Restaurant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Restaurant

def mark_approved(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    queryset.update(is_approved=True)
mark_approved.short_description = "Mark selected restaurants as approved."

class RestaurantAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = ('is_approved',)
    actions = ('mark_approved',)

admin.site.register(Restaurant, RestaurantAdmin)
```

You should then be able to go to your Django admin, and see a restaurant link there. From there you can, filter you list on wether is_approved is True or not.

To mark restaurants as approved, select them in the list, and click on the action dropdown, as shown in the screenshot in the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#ref-contrib-admin-actions)

Comment: Thanks for reply. yes till now good . but after that I wanted to approve them all .like after selecting all there should be option change value of  "is_approved"  field

Comment: You can use custom admin actions: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#ref-contrib-admin-actions

I'll update my answer.

Comment: No button or filter showing. I added code according to your instructions

Comment: Does it show any error messages?
Can you see a dropdown where you can select 'Delete selected restaurants'

Comment: Figured out  it should be written as action= [mark_approved] . thanks for help <3 . from where I can learn about all operations of admin ? can you guide please

Comment: Ah yeah, I usually use tuples for these sorts of fields, but if you forget to add a comma, it will not recognise it as a tuple.

The django admin docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/) are a good place to start.

Answer (score 4):

You could create a [proxy model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#proxy-models) and then update the queryset a bit to achieve your requirement.

```
class UnapprovedRestaurant(Restaurant):
    class Meta:
        proxy=True

class UbapprovedRestaurantAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return Restaurant.objects.filter(is_approved=False)

admin.site.register(UnapprovedRestaurant, UbapprovedRestaurantAdmin)
```

In case you don't want to separate your admin page for these 2 status. Then I prefer you to create a custom filter for your admin page, so that you can filter the data based on the defined condition, like so:

```
class RestaurantFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        return (
            'approved': 'Approved',
            'unapproved': 'Unapproved'
        )

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        value = self.value()
        if value is None:
            return queryset
        elif value == 'approved':
            return queryset.filter(is_approved=True)
        elif value == 'unapproved':
            return queryset.filter(is_approved=False)

class RestaurantAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = (RestaurantFilter, )

admin.site.register(Restaurant, RestaurantAdmin)
```

Comment: hi thanks for reply. I need  a button to change value of filed  is_approved =  True  for all selected un approved entries as well. Can you guide in that aswell ?

Comment: How do you think if you can create both? one for ubapproved restaurant. Another is for approved restaurant. And in Approved restaurant admin page, you could add a button to navigate to Unapproved restaurant and vice versa.

Comment: If you don't want to separate the admin page like that then I prefer you to create a filter on your django admin page.

Comment: @gamer hi, please take a look to see how it does.

Comment: thanks for reply . I will see for now I have got my work done. thanks